# Python class attribute validation on __init__

Tags: python, oop, getter-setter

I'm trying to validate one attribute of my class using setter in the code below. The attribute I want to validate is called '__x' and is set to parameter passed on 'init' method. When I change 'self__x' to 'self.x', it's working as I expect. What I want to is how it's working with 'self.x', while I don't return 'x' attribute anywhere in getter and setter methods and why it's not working with 'self.__x'?

```
class P:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.__x = x  # not working
        # self.x = x  # working

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.__x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x):
        if x < 0:
            self.__x = 0
        else:
            self.__x = x


p = P(-5)
print(p.x)  # prints -5
```

Comment: If you put `self.x = x` you are calling the setter that you wrote. If you put `self.__x = x` you are assiging to the attribute `self.__x` that the property `x` is wrapping.

Comment: but when I put self.x = x and say self__x = 0 in setter, why it doesn't return AttributeError? This is the point that I couldn't understand.

Comment: Why would it cause an error? You can assign whatever attribute you like. `self.__x = x` creates the attribute `__x` for your object.

Comment: There are some classes that can't have attributes, for example, integers. Otherwise, attributes are a free-for-all in Python. This might be weird if you're coming from other languages like Java (can only have attributes you define in the class) or Ruby (can have whatever attributes it wants but they're all private).

Comment: As I understand from your answers, python implicitly calls 'setter' and 'getter' after 'init' function, if they exist. And 'x' defined under 'property' decorator actually overrides 'x' attribute defined inside 'init' function. Is that true?

Comment: @ElginCahangirov not at all. Wait a few minutes and you'll get a detailed answer...

Answer (score 4):

It's like this. Imagine there's a school bully, let's call him Dan, who targets you. There's also Beth, who you like very much. Normally, you want to avoid Dan and meet Beth, but Dan doesn't care and will bop you on the head if he sees you.

Now you also make friends with Joe. He's a gentle giant. Very nice guy. He says to come to his place and he'll make sure he doesn't let Dan in. It all works great: when Dan comes to Joe's door, he's turned away; when Beth comes, Joe lets her in.

The key point is this: it only works as long as Dan is opening the door. If you hear the doorbell and you go out *yourself*, it doesn't work any more.

---

So here, if you do `self.x = -5`, Joe checks the number, sees it's Dan, and sends him packing with a zero. But if you do `self.__x = -5`, Joe never sees Dan. You get a bop on the head.

`self.__x` is just a variable, it can't do any checking on its own. `self.x` is a function though (two of them really, one for reading and one for writing), and it can do whatever it wants - set `self.__x` or refuse to.

Answer (score 1):

Let's begin with the "@decorator" syntax. It's actually only syntactic sugar, so

```
@decorate
def myfunc():
    pass
```

is just a shorthand for

```
def myfunc():
    pass

myfunc = decorate(myfunc)
```

Note that python functions are objects too (as well as classes and modules FWIW) so you can pass functions as arguments to other functions, return functions from functions, store functions as variables or attributes etc.

Now with the `property` class (yes, it's a class): it's only a generic implementation of [the `descriptor` protocol](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html), which is the python mechanism to support computed attributes.

A naive python implementation of `property` would mostly look something like (I ignore the `fdel` and `__del__` parts):

```
class propertytype(type):
    # this is what will allow you 
    # to use `property` as decorator,
    # it will return a new `property` instance
    # with `func` as setter
    def __call__(cls, func):
        return cls(func)

class property(metaclass=propertytype):

    def __init__(self, fget, fset=None):
        self.fget = fget
        self.fset = fset

   # this is the getter
   def __get__(self, instance, cls=None):
       if instance is None:
           return self
       return self.fget(instance)

   # this is the setter (if there's one)
   def __set__(self, instance, value):
       if not self.fset:
           raise AttributeError("Attribute is read-only")
       self.fset(instance, value)

   # and this allows you to use`@myprop.setter` 
   # in your class definition
   def setter(self, func):
       self.fset = func
       return self
```

And finally: while it's good practice to create all instance attributes of an object in the initializer (the `__init__` method), you can actually set existing or new attributes just wherever and whenever you want. Except for a few types that (mainly for implementation reasons) use a totally different way to store attributes (you can look for `slots` if you want to learn more about this), ordinary Python objects are, mainly, dicts in disguise, so `myobj.foo = 'bar'` will usually just store `'bar'` in `self.__dict__['foo']`. Well, if you don't use computed attributes, of course ;)

Ok, now we have the building blocks, let analyze what's going on with your class:

```
class P:
    # let's ignore the initializer for now

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.__x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x):
        if x < 0:
            self.__x = 0
        else:
            self.__x = x
```

This could be rewritten as

```
class P:
    # let's ignore the initializer for now

    def _getx(self):
        return self.__x

    def _setx(self):
        if x < 0:
            self.__x = 0
        else:
            self.__x = x

    x = property(_getx, setx)
```

So now with

```
p = P()
```

when we do:

```
p.x = 5
```

the attribute resolution rules (implemented in `object.__setattr__(self, name, value)`)  will actually lookup "x" on "P", find our "x" property, and since it's a binding descriptor (it has a `__set__` method), call `x.__set__(p, 5)`, which in turn will call `self.fset(p, 5)` (cf `property.__set__()` definition), which will call `p._setx(5)`.

And if we had back the initializer:

```
class P:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    # getter / setter / property definition  here
```

then the very exact thing happens (except the `P` instance is named `self` instead of `p` ) - it actually ends up calling `P._setx(self, x)`.

The only difference with your original implementation is that using the `property` has a decorator, the getter and setter functions do not become methods of the class, they only live as the `fget` and `fset` attributes of the `x` property object.